# One Side Corner Radius issue inside the uitableviewcell in ios objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibezierpath, cornerradius

Am Trying to draw a one side corner radius using UIBezierPath class but it will not taking the full width inside the UITableviewcell. What should I do?

[image]

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:customCell.interviewAutoBtnOutlet.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(5.0,5.0)];

                                 CAShapeLayer *maskLayer1 = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
                                 maskLayer1.frame = customCell.interviewAutoBtnOutlet.bounds;
                                 maskLayer1.path  = maskPath1.CGPath;
                                 customCell.interviewAutoBtnOutlet.layer.mask = maskLayer1;

                                 CAShapeLayer *borderLayer1 = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
                                 borderLayer1.frame = self.view.bounds;
                                 borderLayer1.path  = maskPath1.CGPath;
                                 borderLayer1.lineWidth   = 3.0f;
                                 borderLayer1.strokeColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
                                 borderLayer.fillColor   = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
         [customCell.interviewAutoBtnOutlet.layer addSublayer:borderLayer1];
```

Comment: If you don't round the corner, does the button extend to the edge of the cell?

Comment: @Stonz2  if i used the uibezierpath for the manual and auto button it will not taking the full width inside the tableviewcell.